# PostgreSQL field type to store string, int, or json

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I want to store a table for variables with table definition like below

```
variable
--------
id           int
var_type     int  0: number, 1: string, 2: json
var_name     int
var_value    ??? varchar or jsonb?
```

If I use varchar, how to store the json type variable and if, I am using jsonb how to store the int and string?

The example json value that is stored,

```
[{"name": "Andy", "email" : "andy@mail.id"},{"name": "Cindy", "email" : "cindy@mail.id"}]
```

TIA

Beny

Comment: Variable types aren't really a thing relational schemas are good at. Try to avoid it if possible. Why not simply having a `name` and an `email` column with appropriate types each?

Comment: the idea is to have a variable that can be number, string or json (array). the example of  name and email aboce is just an example. it can be anything, [{'first_name' : 'Andy', 'last_name' : 'Robertson'}, {'first_name' : 'Cindy', 'last_name' : 'McGill'}].

Answer (score 1):

When you have data and you don't know the structure, use a single jsonb column. JSON can handle strings, numbers, and more JSON.

```
{
  "string": "basset hounds got long ears",
  "number": 23.42,
  "json": [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Don't try to cram them all into a single array. Put them in separate rows.

- One row: `{"name": "Andy", "email" : "andy@mail.id"}`
- Another row: `{"name": "Cindy", "email" : "cindy@mail.id"}`

However, your example feels like its avoiding designing a schema. JSONB is useful, but overusing it defeats the point of a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

```
create table people (
  id bigserial primary key,

  // Columns for known keys which can have constraints.
  name text not null,
  email text not null,

  // JSONB for extra keys you can't predict.
  data jsonb
)
```

Use the [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to query individual pairs.

```
select
  name, email, data->>'favorite dog breed'
from some_table
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. The thing is that name and email are there not because they are permanently there. Another JSON type variable is [{'first_name' : 'Andy', 'last_name' : 'Robertson'}, {'first_name' : 'Cindy', 'last_name' : 'McGill'}].

Comment: if I stored as varchar, How can I cast this varchar to this json where var_type is json?

Comment: @BenySetiawan Don't store it as varchar, use a single jsonb column for everything.

Comment: @BenySetiawan [Here's an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8779e8328fc13effee9aa35fbe40c95). Again, I advise you consider a more traditional table structure before slapping everything into jsonb.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Schwern. I follow your suggestion that I move the important thing to a field and only leave unstructured fields in the jsonb field.